Виртуальный жёсткий диск или Виртуальная Машина?
Итак. В винде можно создавать виртуальные жёсткие диски. По слухам, эта штука безопасна.. Вроде...
Я не слишком опытный пользователь, но также слышал о VirtualBox, у меня даже есть образ системы.
Но вот незадача, все это я начал из-за очень требовательных программ: игр, не все из которых на 100% будут скачаны официально.
Что надёжнее и при этом жрет меньше производительности?
Под надежностью подразумеваю изолированность системы от диска, чтобы не боясь можно было скачивать и не опасаться майнеров и жестких вирусов.

с виртуальным жестким диском я не буду бояться его форматировать под ноль, если это будет "изолятором", то по идее вирусы никак оттуда не выберутся.

P.S. Без негатива, если это не так работает, объясните, я не нашёл толковых постов по этой теме. Отталкиваюсь практически от ничего.

под виртуальным жестким диском я имею в виду функцию "создание виртуального жёсткого диска" при помощи Win+R "diskmgmt.msc".


Виртуальный диск - это не про изоляцию от вирусов вообще. Вирус выберется с него, как только вы запустите программу с этого диска.

Получается лучше использовать VirtualBox?

Лучше не тащить в рот всякую гадость

Ну по факту, чо сказать

Если вы используете windows 10/11, то в ней есть своя песочница, в которой вы можете запускать и тестировать "непроверенный софт"

Но, прецеденты побега из виртуальных машин / песочниц - известны.  Я бы не советовал полагаться ни на VirtualBox, ни на песочницу.

виртуальный диск - ни чем не отличается от обычного диска; отличия только в размещении; физический диск - собственно и находится на физическом носителе, т.е. каком то физическом диске, будь то самсунг/хуникс и так далее - на физическом носителе и лежит [размещается] например партиция [диск С:], однако же виртуальный диск на то и виртуальный) он размещается в памяти - это ram-диск; но он такой же как и все диски; с точностью до размещения - в этом разница, а другой разницы - нет; отсюда следует, что предполагаемая вирусьня запущенная с ram-диска - без проблем запросто "перебежит" на любые диски

По-моему, лучшая система виртуализации - VMWare. VMWare Workstation Player бесплатный. Есть ещё Hyper-V от Microsoft, тоже норм. Работает в Windows 10/11, устанавливается через компоненты системы. Песочница на нём и работает, мне кажется.

VirtualBox даст изоляцию от хост системы, но с производительностью будут сложности.
